# Plotting error function in a specific range in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to plot the error function in a specific range: `(5,6)` on the x-axis and `(0.6,1)` on the y-axis. But I am getting an empty plot. I don't know why that's the case. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import special

x = np.linspace(5, 6, 100)  # Generate 100 equally spaced points between 5 and 6
y = special.erf(x)  # Compute the error function values for each x

# Apply the desired y-range
y = 0.5 * (y + 1)  # Normalize y to the range (0, 1)
y = 0.4 * y + 0.6  # Scale and shift y to the range (0.6, 1)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('$x$')
plt.ylabel('$\mathrm{erf}(x)$')
plt.title('Error Function')
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylim(0.6, 1)  # Set the y-axis limits
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between your the max and min for y is super small (of the order of 1e-13), but your set `ylim` is relatively huge, hence it is not visible. You can fix the problem by either removing the `ylim` or choosing a suitable (a very very small range) value for `ylim`. For completeness, both versions of your  code, with `plt.ylim` line commented out will produce the following image.

Code without ylim:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import special

x = np.linspace(5, 6, 100)  # Generate 100 equally spaced points between 5 and 6
y = special.erf(x)  # Compute the error function values for each x

# Apply the desired y-range
y = 0.5 * (y + 1)  # Normalize y to the range (0, 1)
y = 0.4 * y + 0.6  # Scale and shift y to the range (0.6, 1)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('$x$')
plt.ylabel('$\mathrm{erf}(x)$')
plt.title('Error Function')
plt.grid(True)
# plt.ylim(0.6, 1)  # Set the y-axis limits
# plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Code with sutiable ylim:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import special

x = np.linspace(5, 6, 100)  # Generate 100 equally spaced points between 5 and 6
y = special.erf(x)  # Compute the error function values for each x

# Apply the desired y-range
y = 0.5 * (y + 1)  # Normalize y to the range (0, 1)
y = 0.4 * y + 0.6  # Scale and shift y to the range (0.6, 1)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('$x$')
plt.ylabel('$\mathrm{erf}(x)$')
plt.title('Error Function')
plt.grid(True)
plt.ylim(0.9999999999999, 1)  # Set the y-axis limits
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]